# Drop down menu not working on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, screen-size

My drop-down(up) menu works fine on all browsers and on chrome mobile preview, but on an actual mobile device, it doesn't work.
On an ipad it doesn't show up at all and on a phone, you can just see the very bottom of the text inside the menu.

I've tried changing the z-index.
I also considered setting a fixed height for the menu, but then it ends up looking uneven depending on your window size...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
        .navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar span {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1vw 5vw 1vw 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 2.5vw;
    }

    #home {
        float: left;
    }


    .dropup {
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropup-content {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 3.5vw;
        min-width: 100vw;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #clickContact {
        background-color: aqua;
    }

    #clickAbout {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .show {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <footer>
        <div class="navbar">
          <span id="home">Home</span>

          <div>
            <span class="dropup" onclick="contactFunction()">Contact</span>
                <div class="dropup-content" id="clickContact">
                    <p>some other stuff</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            <span class="dropup" onclick="aboutFunction()">About</span>
                <div class="dropup-content" id="clickAbout">
                    <p>Some stuff</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>


    <script>
        function contactFunction() {
            document.getElementById("clickContact").classList.toggle("show");
            document.getElementById("clickAbout").classList.remove("show");
        }

        function aboutFunction() {
            document.getElementById("clickAbout").classList.toggle("show");
            document.getElementById("clickContact").classList.remove("show");
        }

        window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (!event.target.matches('.dropup')) {
            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropup-content");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
              var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
              if (openDropdown.classList.contains("show")) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove("show");
              }
            }
          }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to increase the font size of the menu on mobile only. And also increase the position of `dropup-content`.
You can try this CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 860px) {
.navbar span {
    font-size: 5.5vw;
}
.dropup-content {
    bottom: 9.5vw;
}}
```

Comment: Thanks, MistaPrime, I tried adjusting those elements so that the formatting looked right on Chrome mobile preview, but the drop-downs still fail to appear when using an iPad or phone...

Comment: If you found this answer helpful please upvote it and check the gray tickmark.